What eactly did Pierre Cartier mean about contradiction in categorical reasoning?
In a 2009 EMS Newsletter interview of Pierre Cartier titled "The Castle of Groups" (http://javier.fresan.perso.math.cnrs.fr/castle-of-groups.pdf) Cartier says (p.32 right column): "Nowadays, one of the most interesting points in mathematics is that, although all categorical reasonings are formally contradictory, we use them and we never make a mistake."
What exactly does he mean here when he says "all categorical reasonings are formally contradictory"?

It would be helpful to quote the whole paragraph there. I think the context explains itself well.

I can't pretend to know Cartier's thoughts, but his next sentence gives us a clue:

Grothendieck provided a partial solution in terms of universes but a revolution of the foundations similar to what Cauchy and Weierstrass did for analysis is still to arrive.

My guess is that Cartier is referring to how we talk about "the category of categories" and other such things. Formally, a category of categories leads to contradiction (just like a set of all sets), so if we want to be precise, we need to talk about a category of "small" categories. Even that isn't satisfactory: the collection of all categories isn't a set, so what is it? When we start talking about things like indexed categories (pseudofunctors into the category of large categories), things get even shakier.
Grothendieck's solution that Cartier is referring to is to work within a framework of "universes", based on some large cardinal axioms. From what I understand, we have a sequence of larger and larger "universes of set theory": your smallest universe forms the category of "small" sets; the next larger universe can be used to talk about the category of small sets as a small set, and so on.

Yes, it seems clear that Cartier is not claiming that categorical reasoning is contradictory in itself, but rather that when we do such reasoning we allow ourself to be very relaxed with foundational issues, which does lead to a fair amount of reasoning that is formally unsound (although as he points out that basically never backfires).

This question has already been discussed in https://mathoverflow.net/q/23564/152921, I presume, up to a satisfactory explanation.
However, see also Pierre Cartier's own presentation "Living in a Contradictory World: Categories vs. Sets?" in the 2009 workshop Category Theory and Related Fields: History and Prospects.
